# Why doesn't google analytics track specific user views and other activities?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I create a custom dimension to track each user activities and set ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue) . `dimensionValue` is a user id when logged in. From the picture, it doesn't show any values and I have been waiting for more than 24 hours.  [image]

**Custom dimension settings**

[image]

**my google analytics debugger**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure value is sent to Analytics?

Comment: hi michele, yes my website is tracked. I can see the general report but not for specific user. I tried your suggestion before. The weird thing is I set up with the same config to track the same website with my test account and it works. But it doesn't work on my company account.

Comment: I meant if you see the userId sent to Analytics in console.

Comment: how can you check if userId is sent to Analytics? I set my code ga('set', 'userId', userId) and ga('set', 'dimension1', userId)

Comment: Make sure that in the call that the browser makes to Google Analytics there are those parameters (cd1) and their values in the querystring.

Comment: I've uploaded the google analytics debugger image. It shows the data is sent

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Google Analytics debugger I can see that the `userId` and `custom dimension 1` are **not sent** along with the pageview hit.

It appears that you have set then but they are not in the call:

[image]

So I think you are defining them after sending the pageview.

Check where they are in your code and enter those commands **before** send *pageview* or try incorporating them into the command itself, i.e. for custom dimensions like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  '6368'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're calling `ga('set', ...)` before `ga('send',...)` command. Also, check if there are any error messages in the console related to `ga('set', ...)`